# how to make inside round container in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a widget like this

[image]

Comment: can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you tried this package?
https://pub.dev/packages/ticketview

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CustumPaint widget and manually create any specific shape. The child of CustumPaint should be the content you want inside the coupon.

```
class Coupon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      child: // YOUR_CONTENT
      painter: CouponPainter,
    );
  }
}

class CouponPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // PROGRAMMATICALLY DRAW THE SHAPE HERE
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: can you update the answer by  drawing the shape?